# How to create own domain extension?

Tags: dns, personalization

Like `bit.ly`, `goo.gl`, `is.gd`, `j.mp`, `migre.me` etc. use their own domain extension `.ly`, `.gl`, `.gd`, `.mp`, `.me` etc. How can I create my own personalize domain extension like `.gbsif`? Please help.

Comment: Wrong place for this question. But I will say you can't just go about creating these yourself. These guys control that: http://icann.org/

Comment: .ly = Libya, .gl = Greenland, .gd = Grenada, .mp = Northern Mariana Islands, .me = Montenegro. So... not their own at all.

Comment: and .ly, .gl etc. aren't "their own tlds", they are country tlds like .de, .at, .es, .uk etc. (spender bet me by 25 seconds on that ;) )

Comment: @spender: Thanks. But why you posted that as a comment? It may be an answer.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's telling you that the fundamental premise of your question is incorrect. Anyone can look this up on the good links provided in the existing answers.

Comment: To find all the country level extentions, go to http://www.101domain.com/domain_extension.htm

Comment: ".oracle  generic  Oracle Corporation" is a personalized extension... there must be some way to create it or contact them... figuring out how... ??? got from this link http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: It's funny that you referred [`.xyz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.xyz) domain.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't. Only IANA can.

> Management of most top-level domains is delegated to responsible organizations by the Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN), which operates the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) and is in charge of maintaining the DNS root zone.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain

Here's a list of available TLDs:

- http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/
- http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: Paul Vixie advocates the use of ORSN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Root_Server_Network

Comment: Technically, you can't register your own Top-Level-Domain (TLD) as it's under the responsibility of the ICANN. As umeboshi explained, the ORSN was a possiblity (until its closure in 2019 for those who have not noticed the dates).
Today (2023), it's possible to request an existing registrar to support you in launching a new TLD (the registrar will do the submitting to ICANN in your stead), but it comes with a fees depending on the registrar and how much they can sell this new TLD. It can cost as much as $185,000 if not more and the registrar will be the one who own access right over the TLD.

Answer (score 15):

You can run your own nameserver and add a new tld there. But this won't help you much, as the TLD will only be visible to the users who are using your own nameserver. 
The "official" TLD like ".ly" are countries, see: [official list](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/)

Comment: Some countries are created more equal than others though. Tuvalu earns a very good rate because of the happy conincidence that their TLD is .tv.

Answer (score 12):

The ICANN website *does* have a Contact page, and one subject category *is* "New gTLDs", so they probably get requests like this a lot. I don't know if they'd actually create an extension just for you, but if they get a lot of the same requests, I'm sure they'd do something about it.